# I can not download my python package from nexus pip Repositories

Tags: python, pip, nexus

I create a self repositorie by nexus , and upload my own python package to nexus repositorie  by twine , but I can not install them by pip install.

[image: The host pip repositorie in nsxus]

I upload the python package by:
`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

`twine upload --repository-url http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/wangs_host/ dist/*`

I inistall the python package by:
`pip install -i http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/wangs_host/ package_test_wangs`

but it does not work, what should I do ? Thanks.

[image: pip install result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index URL isn’t right, it needs to end with “/simple”.  See here:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it help me solve the problem.